# Unable to save an image after an array

Tags: python, image, numpy, numpy-ndarray, save-image

I got this Error :

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/runner/Image-Loader/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2992, in fromarray
mode, rawmode = _fromarray_typemap[typekey]
KeyError: ((1, 1, 5), '|u1')

Here is my code :

```
img = Image.open(f"IMG/{thumb[0]}_{thumb[1]}x{thumb[1]}.png")

height,width = img.size
lum_img = Image.new('L', [height,width] , 0)

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(lum_img)
draw.pieslice([(0,0), (height,width)], 0, 360, fill = 255, outline = "white")
img_arr =np.array(img)
lum_img_arr =np.array(lum_img)
final_img_arr = np.dstack((img_arr,lum_img_arr))


im = Image.fromarray(final_img_arr)
im.save("filename.png")
```

I want a script who open an image and I want to crop in circle the image like they do here : [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cropping-an-image-in-a-circular-way-using-python/](https://www.stackoverflow.com/). But when I want to save my Image, I got the error. Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

The pixel format of `img` is **RGBA** and not RGB.

Replace `Image.open(f"IMG/{thumb[0]}_{thumb[1]}x{thumb[1]}.png")` with:

```
Image.open(f"IMG/{thumb[0]}_{thumb[1]}x{thumb[1]}.png").convert('RGB')
```

---

Because pixel format is RGBA, there are 4 color channels instead of 3 (the `A` channel applies "Alpha" transparency channel).

The result of `final_img_arr = np.dstack((img_arr,lum_img_arr))` is 5 "color channels" instead of 4 channels, and 5 channels is does not apply a valid image format.

We my verify that the number of channels is valid by printing the shape of `final_img_arr` before saving: `print(final_img_arr.shape)`
Make sure that the shape is `(height, width, 4)`

Answer (score 0):

Your code would work if you would use .jpg images instead of .png images.
One cause is because the shape of the .png array is of incompatible form for the `Image.fromarray(final_img_arr)` calculation. You either need to save your images as .jpg before hand or find a different way to transform .png final_img_array back into an image.

```
png shape: final_img_array->(329, 212, 5)

jpg shape: final_img_array -> (329, 212, 4)
```

this could work to reshape your .png into an compatible shape:

```
im = Image.fromarray(final_img_arr[:,:,[0,1,2,4]])
```

using `final_img_arr[:,:,[0,1,2,4]]` will keep all the cells (pixels in your pictures) but cut out the column[3] out of every cell. This column usually contains transparency information. This means your pictures will be exactly the same except if they have for example a transparent background.

Comment: Tnak you very mutch, it work perfectly !